# What's exactly happening when I press F11 in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, build, continuous-integration

The NetBeans command to run an Ant build for a project is <kbd>F11</kbd>. I always believed that the target that it executes is named "default". I overrode the default target to do nothing other than simply flag that it ran. When I manually run the target from Ant, or by selecting the particular default target in Netbeans, I get the expected "flagging" behavior.

However, when I press <kbd>F11</kbd>, Netbeans runs the init, deps-jar, compile, and jar targets. It seems that I actually did not override the default target, as far as NetBeans is concerned.

I'm doing this so I can effectively decouple my build script from my IDE, but I get the impression that NetBeans isn't helping with this.

Essentially, what I want is to override the default target so that when I press <kbd>F11</kbd>, targets that I specifically add are run. Is this achieved by eliminating the build-impl.xml file?

Comment: You should remove what you learned from your question, post it as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little luck, I figured out how to define a keyboard short-cut for custom defined targets. Create Shortcut -> Create Keyboard Shortcut does the trick. It seems to me that NetBeans has a predefined <kbd>F11</kbd> target that won't change. It's as close as I'll get, but at least I have an <kbd>F12</kbd> and an Ant target now.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is actually running the dist target when you press build <kbd>F11</kbd>, so what you can is to override it in the build.xml file to get it to do whatever you want. Just go to build-impl.xml and copy paste the dist target to build.xml, and then modify it from there.